# How I receive the last windowed Kafka message in Session TimeWindow with aggregation + suppress?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, stream, apache-kafka-streams

Like I say in the title, I want to receive the last windowed message. At the moment, I am doing it by using the suppress method, but first of all, a little description.

I have a producer that sends to the Kafka Streams a list of Integers that needs to be added for a given time. For that, I am using a SessionTimeWindow that I want to keep aggregating until we receive the last message. After the window is closed, I want to receive the last count value.
This is the topology:

```java
StreamsBuilder builder = new StreamsBuilder();

builder.stream("input_topic", Consumed.with(Serdes.String(), new Serdes.ListSerde<Integer>()))
  .flatMapValues((value) -> value)
  .groupByKey(Grouped.with(Serdes.String(), Serdes.Integer()))
  .windowedBy(SessionWindows.ofInactivityGapWithNoGrace(Duration.ofSeconds(10)))
  .aggregate(
    ()-> 0,
    ((key, value, aggregate) -> aggregate + value),
    ((aggKey, aggOne, aggTwo) -> aggOne + aggTwo),
    Materialized.with(Serdes.String(), Serdes.Integer()))
  .suppress(Suppressed.untilWindowCloses(Suppressed.BufferConfig.unbounded()))
  .toStream()
  .map((key, value) -> new KeyValue<String, Integer>(key.key(), value))
  .to("output_topic", Produced.with(Serdes.String(), Serdes.Integer()));

Topology topology = builder.build();
```

I tried to run the topology with a local kafka server or using the TopologyTestDriver to send some messages. Still, I always got the same result, any message in the output topic.

These are my stream configs for the TestTopologyDriver:

```java
Properties properties = new Properties();
properties.put(StreamsConfig.APPLICATION_ID_CONFIG, "app");        
properties.put(StreamsConfig.TOPOLOGY_OPTIMIZATION_CONFIG, StreamsConfig.OPTIMIZE);       
properties.put(StreamsConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "test");       
properties.put(StreamsConfig.COMMIT_INTERVAL_MS_CONFIG, 0);
```

and the test definition:

```java
TopologyTestDriver topologyTestDriver = new TopologyTestDriver(topology, properties, Instant.now());

TestInputTopic<String, List<Integer>> inputTopic = topologyTestDriver.createInputTopic("input_topic", new StringSerializer(), new Serdes.ListSerde<Integer>().serializer());
TestOutputTopic<String, Integer> outputTopic = topologyTestDriver.createOutputTopic("output_topic", new StringDeserializer(), new IntegerDeserializer());

inputTopic.pipeInput("1", List.of(1,2,3));
inputTopic.pipeInput("1", List.of(1));
List<TestRecord<String, Integer>> outputList = outputTopic.readRecordsToList();

assertEquals(1, outputList.size());
assertEquals(7, outputList.get(0).value());
```

Using the TestTopologyDriver, I tried a lot of cases:

- Run the TopologyTestDriver in another thread and sleep the main thread without any result.
- Send the records with a Timestamp.
- Use a timestamp extractor.
- Call the `TopologyTestDriver.advanceWallClockTime();`

In all the cases the output is an empty list. When I used a local kafka server I didn't get any messsage (as same of the test)

What I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

Since most operations are timestamp based, usually it is enough to:

1. inputTopic.advanceTime([Duration needed for message to pass through all windows/suppressions])
2. inputTopic.pipeInput("dummyMessage", List.of(...))

After this you should be able to read outputTopic.

Alternatively, you can use inputTopic.pipeInput("messaageKey", value, timestamp) and tweak these timestamps. And then send dummy message with appriopriate future timestamp.